# Non-aritho geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, real-numbers

Forgive me for any mistake in the proposal of the problem

**Problem**

> If $\sqrt{t}+\sqrt{t+1}+\sqrt{t+2}+\sqrt{t+3}+\cdots +t=x$. Find the value of $t$ in terms of $x$

I have tried doing it with some examples but couldn't get a simple form
I have also tried by squaring every number and then factoring it to get an equation in $t$ and then taking the result as $Y$ and then trying to establish a relation between $x,Y$ but I couldn't do so.

Please help me.Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Confirmation: You have written the last term of the sequence as $t$, Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it really which makes the problem more tough,According to me

Comment: It means that  the last term it's $\sqrt{t+(t^2-t)}.$ I think it's nothing.

Comment: Yes, I should have actually written it like that but I am way too lazy in such things.

Comment: It implies that $t^2-t \in \mathbb{N}$... if you can express the number $n(x)$ of  terms needed in the LHS, you will just have to solve $t^2-t = n(x)$.

Comment: That's a really nice idea to start this problem but what do you meany by "if you can express.....LHS"

Comment: I mean the number of the "$\sqrt{t+i}$" terms needed to obtain the value $x$. This number depending on $x$ may be denote by $n(x)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $i$

Comment: $i=0, 1, 2, \dots....$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72582/discussion-between-mathswiz-and-netchaiev).

Comment: I posted a proposition of answer

Answer (score 0):

Let be 
$$ n(x):=\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \Big\{\sum_{k\leq i}\sqrt{t+k} \leq x\Big\} $$
(there is an obvious finite algorithm to compute it, given $t$ and $x$),
then the solution will be obtained by solving
$$ t^2-t = n(x)$$
 Ps:   $n(x)$ need $t$ and $x$ to be computed, but the question was expressing $t$ in terms of $x$, and I think this is an answer (maybe there is a better one, though).

Comment: What do you mean by sup,sir?

Comment: the bigger $i\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{k\leq i}\sqrt{t+k} \leq x$

Comment: Do you mean maximum by "the bigger"?

Comment: yes, on a finite set, sup=max

Comment: the matter is that $n$ is not a function of $x$ alone but also of $t$: so the $t^2-t=n(x,t)$ does not help much.

Comment: You are right @G Cab never thought about it

Comment: I already made that remark ($n$ depending on $x$ and $t$) in my "Ps". It gives an algorithm to express $t$ in term of $x$ (not finding $t$ thanks to $x$)... I agreed : "(maybe there is a better one, though)."